# How to add coreData relationships in objective c

Tags: core-data

I need to set relationships for cards and note, below is the sample code

Cards:

```objective-c
AppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

entityObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:_appDel.managedObjectContext];

[entityObj setValue: userName forKey:@"custname"];
[entityObj setValue: userDesignation forKey:@"custdesignation"];
[entityObj setValue: userComapnay forKey:@"custcompany"];

[AppDelegate saveContxt];
```

Notes:

```objective-c
AppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

entityObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:_appDel.managedObjectContext];

[entityObj setValue: userName forKey:@"notes"];
[entityObj setValue: userDesignation forKey:@"date"];

[AppDelegate saveContxt];
```

How to set relationship for above two models?

Answer (score 1):

First, core data is not a database. Don't treat it like one. It's a persistent object graph.

How do you usually make relations between core data objects? This is no different than any other relationship. I assume there’s a 1:n relation, where one user can have multiple notes? You just model that relationship in core data and add the created note to the notes array of the user.

Read a tutorial about relationships in core data. This seems similar to what you want to achieve: https://hackernoon.com/core-data-relationships-d813ed66ba8c